# How can i use this ' in Oracle PL SQL on my iPad?

Tags: ipad

I am trying to use apex to run sql commands but when i try this

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE JOB = ‘CLERK’
```

I get invalid character. However on my PC, I type

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE JOB = 'CLERK'
```

It works fine. I copied the ' to my iPad clipboard to type queries. So my question is where can i find it on the smart keyboard by Apple or their virtual keyboard.

Comment: I removed your Oracle and PL/SQL tags since your question has nothing to do with them - it is just an iOS question. You shouldn't even have Oracle and PL/SQL in your title, but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 3):

Long press the ! symbol in the iPad keyboard to get '. [You could see this](https://www.iphonejd.com/iphone_jd/2013/03/ipad-tip-quick-quotation-marks.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to system prefaces, keyboard. In the keyboard window click on the text tab. In this window, on the right, is an option to use smart quotes. Uncheck the box.